# "except" statement with same exception class as parameter twice

Tags: python, exception, syntax, django-orm

In Python, how can I use `except` block with same exception name twice in `try/except` statements without need to wrap code into one more `try/except` block?

Simple example (here **each** call of `pages.get` may raise the exception):

```
try:
    page = pages.get(lang=lang)
except Page.DoesNotExist:
    if not lang == default_lang:
        page = pages.get(lang=default_lang)
    else:
        raise Page.DoesNotExist
except Page.DoesNotExist:
    page = pages[0]
```

For now, in my Django app I do handling like this (but I don't want "extra" `try` block here):

```
try:
    try:
        page = pages.get(lang=lang)
    except Page.DoesNotExist:
        if not lang == default_lang:
            page = pages.get(lang=default_lang)
        else:
            raise Page.DoesNotExist
except Page.DoesNotExist:
    page = pages[0]
```

Any handling code better than above is appreciated! :)

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: You can't. Perhaps you can tell us why you think you need to do this so we can tell you why you don't need to do it

Comment: I agree, I dont think this is a good idea. It means that you have two code paths that are triggered by the same thing, doing different things. Think about the try/catch as an if/else statement.

Comment: Really too curious not to ask: why don't you put `page = pages[0]` instead of the `raise Page.DoesNotExist` in the first try block? (of course this would help me a lot to understand the question better)

Comment: @Gabber **each** `pages.get` calling may raise the exception, so last `except` statement just try to catch this possible exception

Comment: Got it, thanks! I'd just go with your working solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use same multiple exceptions in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54897829/how-to-use-same-multiple-exceptions-in-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I handle multiple same Error type in Python in try except block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55764498/how-can-i-handle-multiple-same-error-type-in-python-in-try-except-block)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this either and expect the `elif` to execute:

```
if foo == bar:
  # do "if"
elif foo == bar:
  # do "elif"
```

And there's no reason to do this, really. Same for your `except` concern.

Here's the disassembled Python bytecode of your first code snippet:

```
 13           0 SETUP_EXCEPT            10 (to 13)

 14           3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (NameError)
              6 RAISE_VARARGS            1
              9 POP_BLOCK           
             10 JUMP_FORWARD            44 (to 57)

 15     >>   13 DUP_TOP             
             14 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (NameError)
             17 COMPARE_OP              10 (exception match)
             20 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       35
             23 POP_TOP             
             24 POP_TOP             
             25 POP_TOP             

 16          26 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (NameError)
             29 RAISE_VARARGS            1
             32 JUMP_FORWARD            22 (to 57)

 17     >>   35 DUP_TOP             
             36 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (NameError)
             39 COMPARE_OP              10 (exception match)
             42 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       56
             45 POP_TOP             
             46 POP_TOP             
             47 POP_TOP             

 18          48 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             51 PRINT_ITEM          
             52 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             53 JUMP_FORWARD             1 (to 57)
        >>   56 END_FINALLY         
        >>   57 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             60 RETURN_VALUE
```

It's obvious that the first `COMPARE_OP` to `NameError` (at offset 17) will catch the exception and jump to after the second such comparison (at offset 36).

Answer (score 2):

Though, I can't currently figure out a better way for your use-case, Python's `try/except` statement has some extra features:

```
try:
  pass
  # run your code
except:
  pass
  # run your error handling, etc.. 
else:
  pass
  # is run whenever an exception didn't happen
finally:
  pass
  # will be executed always (good for cleaning up)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create a function to get pages for you, eg. like this:

```
def get_page(language):
    if language == default_lang:
        lang_list = [language]
    else:
        lang_list = [language, default_lang]

    for lang in lang_list:
        try:
            return pages.get(lang=lang)
        except Page.DoesNotExist:
            pass

    return pages[0]
```

Comment: @neoascetic You could just have `for lang in set(language, default_lang)` instead of the first four lines too. You should also be passing in `pages` to the function.

Comment: @detly Sets are unordered, and `default_lang` should be tried last, so a list is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Exception in Python or any Sane Language never works the way you are intending it to be. Every time an exception is raised it should trace back a stack/scope. Any exception that is raised in the current scope can only be handled once per stack/scope. 
Think it this was, every scope has a single exception handling mechanism, with a filter function which simply filters the exception as the order mentioned for a match. If a match happens, it is handled as per the designated Exception Handler. If any exception is re-thrown or generated it should be handled by the next Exception Handling Mechanism which is just immediate to the next scope.

Looking in to the example, I am wondering why would you like to complicate the fact by raising another exception but rather not handling it in the else block

```
try:
    page = pages.get(lang=lang)
except Page.DoesNotExist:
    if not lang == default_lang:
        page = pages.get(lang=default_lang)
    else:
        page = pages[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions raised in an `except` block are not handled by the same `try`/`except` block, so your example cannot work. Even if you could, your example would actually give rise to an infinite loop, as the first `except NameError` would simply catch the exception raised from within itself again, and raise `NameError` again, and so on forever.

This feature is by design, as it would otherwise be impossible to write an exception handler that inspects an exception but then raises the exception outwards. `except` blocks only handle exceptions thrown from within the `try` block. If you want to handle an exception thrown from within an `except` block, that block needs to be inside a `try` block.