# How to chain trying/handling operations with the same exception type?

Tags: python

I am attempting several similar operations until one of them succeeds:

```
a=[1,2,3]
try:
    print(a[6])
except IndexError:
    print(a[7])
except IndexError:
    print(a[1])
```

However, the second failure is not caught by the second handler:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I know that this can be handled by nesting, but this is very verbose and obscures that the operations are all very similar:

```
a=[1,2,3]
try:
    print(a[6])
except IndexError:
    try:
        print(a[7])
    except IndexError:
        print(a[1])
```

Is there any good approach to write the code?

Comment: Multiple `except` blocks on a `try` are used to catch multiple exception types that could happen in the `try`, not exceptions happening in `except` blocks.

Comment: In addition (this is beyond what you're asking) but you can catch different types of exceptions like this `except (IndexError, ValueError) as e`

Answer (score 4):

Use can wrap your `try: ... except:...` with for loop:

```
a = [1,2,3]
for i in [6,7,1]:
    try:
        print(a[i])
    except IndexError:
        pass
# 2
```

Comment: Thank you very much! <br\>
I have used the same way you recommanded!!